# Extract XML node and attribute in R

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML dataset that looks like this:

```
<protocol ID='.'>
    <HEAD></HEAD>
    <block ID='...'>
        <HEAD></HEAD>
        <trial ID='.....'>
            <HEAD></HEAD>
            <seq ID=''>
                <HEAD></HEAD>
                <calibration CLASS='affine-calibration' ID='New Calibration'>
                    <AX>.........</AX>
                    <BX>-........</BX>
                    <AY>.........</AY>
                    <BY>.........</BY>
                    <type>'por'</type>
                </calibration>
                <POR TIME='......'>
                    <PUPIL>.</PUPIL>
                    <BLINK>.</BLINK>
                    <V>...</V>
                    <H>...</H>
                    <PLANEINTRWV>...</PLANEINTRWV>
                    <PLANEINTRWH>...</PLANEINTRWH>
                    <PLANE>.</PLANE>
                </POR>
                <POR TIME='......'>
                    <PUPIL>.</PUPIL>
                    <BLINK>.</BLINK>
                    <V>...</V>
                    <H>...</H>
                    <PLANEINTRWV>...</PLANEINTRWV>
                    <PLANEINTRWH>...</PLANEINTRWH>
                    <PLANE>.</PLANE>
                </POR>
                <POR TIME='......'>
                    <PUPIL>.</PUPIL>
                    <BLINK>.</BLINK>
                    <V>...</V>
                    <H>...</H>
                    <PLANEINTRWV>...</PLANEINTRWV>
                    <PLANEINTRWH>...</PLANEINTRWH>
                    <PLANE>.</PLANE>
                </POR>
            </seq>
        </trial>
        <trial ID='.....'>
            <HEAD></HEAD>
            <seq ID=''>
                <HEAD></HEAD>
                <calibration CLASS='affine-calibration' ID='New Calibration'>
                    <AX>.........</AX>
                    <BX>-........</BX>
                    <AY>.........</AY>
                    <BY>.........</BY>
                    <type>'por'</type>
                </calibration>
                <POR TIME='......'>
                    <PUPIL>.</PUPIL>
                    <BLINK>.</BLINK>
                    <V>...</V>
                    <H>...</H>
                    <PLANEINTRWV>...</PLANEINTRWV>
                    <PLANEINTRWH>...</PLANEINTRWH>
                    <PLANE>.</PLANE>
                </POR>
                <POR TIME='......'>
                    <PUPIL>.</PUPIL>
                    <BLINK>.</BLINK>
                    <V>...</V>
                    <H>...</H>
                    <PLANEINTRWV>...</PLANEINTRWV>
                    <PLANEINTRWH>...</PLANEINTRWH>
                    <PLANE>.</PLANE>
                </POR>
            </seq>
        </trial>
    </block>
</protocol>
```

Using the XML package, what is the cleanest way to extract the POR tag's children and the tag's attributes?

I threw together this kludge that works, but it's slow (due to the xpathSApply call most likely) and is hardly readable.

```
trackToDataFrame = function(file) {
    doc2=xmlParse(file)
    timeStamps = t(xpathSApply(doc2, '//*[@TIME]', function(x) c(name=xmlName(x), xmlAttrs(x))))
    dd2 = xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc2, "//POR"), colClasses=c(rep("integer", 7)))
    dd2 = cbind(dd2, timeStamps)
    dd2
}
```

Calling on the dataset returns:

```
  PUPIL BLINK  V  H PLANEINTRWV PLANEINTRWH PLANE name   TIME
1    NA    NA NA NA          NA          NA    NA  POR ......
2    NA    NA NA NA          NA          NA    NA  POR ......
3    NA    NA NA NA          NA          NA    NA  POR ......
4    NA    NA NA NA          NA          NA    NA  POR ......
5    NA    NA NA NA          NA          NA    NA  POR ......
```

I'm figuring that the whole thing can be done with a single xmlToDataFrame call, but I'm not familiar enough with the XML package to get it to work.

What I'm really interested in is the 'TIME' column along with all of the columns extracted form the xmlToDataFrame call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
require(XML)
Fun1 <- function(xdata){
  dum <- xmlParse(xdata)
  xDf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(dum, "//*/POR"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  xattrs <- xpathSApply(dum, "//*/POR/@TIME")
  xDf$name <- "POR"
  xDf$TIME <- xattrs
  xDf
}

Fun2 <-function(xdata){
  dumFun <- function(x){
    xname <- xmlName(x)
    xattrs <- xmlAttrs(x)
    c(sapply(xmlChildren(x), xmlValue), name = xname, xattrs)
  }
  dum <- xmlParse(xdata)
  as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(dum, "//*/POR", dumFun)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

> identical(Fun1(xdata), Fun2(xdata))
[1] TRUE

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(Fun1(xdata), Fun2(xdata))

         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
1 Fun1(xdata)          100   1.047    2.069     1.044        0          0
2 Fun2(xdata)          100   0.506    1.000     0.504        0          0
  sys.child
1         0
2         0
```

Comment: 2nd method is twice as quick.

Answer (score 2):

A modified version of user1609452:

```
extractXML <-function(xdata, expr, transpo = T){

  # expr should be "//*/Array"
  # cat("[INFO] - expr is an expression of the path usually something like '//*/Array'.")
  # cat("\n[INFO] - Use Transpo = F is you do not want to transpose the output. Just try it out.\n\n")

  dumFun <- function(x){
    xname <- xmlName(x)
    xattrs <- xmlAttrs(x)
    c(sapply(xmlChildren(x), xmlValue), name = xname, xattrs)
  }

  dum <- xmlParse(xdata)
  listxml <- xpathSApply(dum, expr, dumFun)

  if( transpo == T ) {
    data <- as.data.table(t(listxml), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  } else {
    data <- as.data.table(rbind.fill(lapply(listxml,function(y){as.data.frame(y,stringsAsFactors=F)})))
  }

  return(data)
}
```

The objective is here to get the attributes when there is no Children (transpo = F), but you want to get the attributes.

Example below :

```
<Arrays>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam1" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam2" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam1" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam2" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam1" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam2" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam1" Type="Image"/>
    <Array Factor="1.000000" CompressionRate="" CompressionType="" BitsPerPixel="16" Height="515" Width="682" Name="Exp1Cam2" Type="Image" Description=""/>
</Arrays>


extractXML(xdata, "//*/Array", T)

       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8
1: <list> <list> <list> <list> <list> <list> <list> <list>

extractXML(xdata, "//*/Array", F)

    name   Factor CompressionRate CompressionType BitsPerPixel Height Width     Name  Type Description
1: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam1 Image          NA
2: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam2 Image          NA
3: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam1 Image          NA
4: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam2 Image          NA
5: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam1 Image          NA
6: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam2 Image          NA
7: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam1 Image          NA
8: Array 1.000000                                           16    515   682 Exp1Cam2 Image
```